# Advance python scheduler 'tuple' object has no attribute 'public' while starting the scheduler

Tags: apscheduler

Starting the scheduler gives this error. As i can see in the commits that this piece of code was added just 3 days back. So am i missing something here or its a bug ?

```
In /local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/__init__.py in <module>()

1) # These will be removed in APScheduler 4.0.

2) **parsed_version =__import__('pkg_resources').get_distribution('APScheduler').parsed_version

3) version_info = 
tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in  

parsed_version.public.split('.'))**

4) version = parsed_version.base_version

5) release = __version__ = parsed_version.public

**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'public'**
```

Comment: try upgrading setuptools, pip install setuptools --upgrade

Answer (score 8):

I just had this problem and solved it.

Just upgrade setuptools:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

And then it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks Kyle I got the answer after creating an issue within github of apscheduler.

Comment: It worked for me too, but why does this fix the problem? What's the root cause here?

Comment: I'm thinking because setup tools is not properly upgraded it isn't downloading a dependency properly or upgrading the rest of apschelduler properly. or apschelduler is using something within setuptools that is outdated and that's why you need to upgrade. but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using virtualenv than its not advisable to directly upgrade the setuptools package due to some security reasons that's what i got after searching SO.
you should ideally update your virtualenv package itself to latest version which while creating a virtual environment using this command

```
virtualenv <name of virtual environment>
```

install 2 packages.
1) pip
2) setuptools
This way both pip and setuptools will have the latest versions.